# Composite design pattern definition

Tags: oop, design-patterns, composite

In the book Design Patterns : Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software, It says:

"The composite design pattern composes objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies."

In wikipedia the composite design pattern is defined as :

"The composite pattern describes a group of objects that is treated the same way as a single instance of the same type of object. The intent of a composite is to "compose" objects in to tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies."

Picture of composite design pattern:

[image]

If my `Composite` stores `components` as directed acyclic graph( for example it only stores components which are sources of DAC in queue data structure and those sources have references to another components and so on... ) which is not tree because it violates some tree structure condition. Can I still say that I have used composite design pattern?

Comment: I think the title of this question can be, "_Does the composite pattern require a tree data structure?_" And the answer is no, any data structure can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your components in any data structure you like. The point is that each of your components can also be treated as “whole”.

The easiest example is a CompositeView object which contains subviews. CompositeView is a View and its subview objects are also Views. So you have a common interface/abstract class for your objects. It doesn’t matter at all what data structure is used to store subviews.

In the mentioned tree-like structure your list/set/dag/whatever... of components defines a set of child nodes for a given parent node.

Another example could be with **Brick**, **Wall**, **House**, **Block**. A Wall *is composed by* many Bricks; in same way an House *is composed by* four Walls (for the example leave me say that an House doesn't have a roof) and a Block *is composed by*  many Houses. Brick in the Composite pattern represents a Leaf, instead Wall,House,Block are specialisations of Composite, but *all* can be considered as ConstructionComponents (or ConstructionEntities).